# What (if any) is the empirical evidence for ravens being (a) helpful to humans or (b) helpful to predators preying on humans?

Tags: animal-behaviour, ravens

*BACKGROUND:*  I am rereading The Mind of the Raven by [Bernd Heinrich](https://www.google.com/search?q=bernd+heinrich&rlz=1C1FKPE_enUS989US989&oq=&aqs=chrome.0.69i59i450l3.2147243057j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), an eminent biologist and naturalist.  Edward O. Wilson gave this book an excellent review.

Based on his many observations of wild ravens and ravens he raised from chickhood in Maine and Vermont, plus his non-invasive experiments in raven problem solving, Bernd concludes that "...ravens are able to manipulate mental images for solving problems and .... [see] with their minds at least some of what they have seen with their eyes."   This is a cautious way of saying that ravens are spookily intelligent.

*THE QUESTION:*  Heinrich reports several instances of people reporting that ravens have helped them.  For example, one woman reported noticing a cougar lying in wait for her because of a raven's movement that caught her eye.  "That raven saved my life" she declared.  BUT, Heinrich postulates that it is more likely that the raven led the cougar to her, in order to share in the kill.

He bases this postulate on widespread evidence that ravens and wolves share  wolf kills, the ravens descending almost instantly on a wolf kill.  He cites Odin, the Norse god as portrayed with two wolves at his side, and a raven perched on each shoulder.  He implied that Norse raids, bloody affairs, provided good eating for ravens. Heinrich postulates that wolves and ravens evolved to cooperate with each other over many tens (hundreds ?) of thousands of years, and that ravens recognize that other predators also provide food, notably human hunters, at whose kills they quickly arrive.

Heinrich's book was published in 1999.  So the question is: how have these postulates of ravens (a) helping and/or (b) exploiting humans developed in since this book was published?  Or is Heinrich still on the cutting edge?

Note:  The behavior of ravens varies somewhat with geography. but I am not going to specify ravens of a particular continent, country or locality.

Comment: Web of Science has 24 hits on "raven behavior" in a journal article title, and none are relevant.

Comment: If the raven was intelligent enough to lead a cougar to "lie in wait", i.e. to a place where it anticipated a human would pass, surely it would also know that it must not tip off the human to the danger... I do know that animals *can* lead you: when I arrived at a relative's house one of their dogs clearly wanted me to follow it to where the senior dog was sleeping; in the movies a horse leads someone to where the rider fell; etc.

Comment: @Weather Vane  I cannot find the passage quickly, and the index is not specific enough, but I will continue to look for it because I thought the same thingas you did.   The author's research does find that ravens differ in intelligence, although it says nothing about differences in patience, perseverance, stealthiness.  Maybe ravens, through long observation, have concluded that humans are unobservant and so a little easing of position will go unnoticed.  Or maybe the raven really was warning the woman.

Comment: Or if you are not a researcher looking for verification of theories, neither? It's going to be pretty tough proving the raven's motivations (if any). Aside: I do believe in intelligence in non-human animals.

Comment: The paper https://bioone.org/journals/journal-of-raptor-research/volume-52/issue-4/JRR-17-93.1/Winter-Scavenging-of-Ungulate-Carrion-By-Bald-Eagles-Common-Ravens/10.3356/JRR-17-93.1.short includes "Bald Eagles relied on ravens for discovery and sentinel duties, whereas both species depended on coyotes for accessibility." but that is about interacting on carcasses.

Comment: @JonCuster good find. But does that equate to cooperation or to opportunistic behaviour subject to their respective skills & abilities in the presence of other competitors?

Comment: @WeatherVane - to me it reads as opportunistic - ravens find it first, bald eagles join in, but both need coyotes to show up to rip the carcass apart more to expose more stuff. It does not read that the 'plan' it, it just happens that way and they each take advantage of the others.

Comment: Why would the ravens not be able to choose for themselves what to do. Why would there be bias towards a certain species?